# How can I accept multiple classes for one function argument?

Tags: c++

Say I have two classes, ClassA and ClassB.

ClassB inherits ClassA, and has some additional functions and variables.

Is it possible for me to make a function that can accept either ClassA or ClassB as the same argument, and let me determine which one was used?

Comment: You can use polymorphism and Real Time Type Information (RTTI).

Comment: Well yes, and in several different ways, but my immediate thought wasjust overload the function and then you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: Can you give some detail about what your function is supposed to do?

Comment: @Tony Hopkinson - I don't know why I didn't think of that in the first place, but overloading actually did fix my problem in this case.

Comment: As soon as i have to add an is test, I figure either my design is not as good as it could be, or the tools I'm using aren't the best choice. Stiol loads of is tests in my code, but its not my default option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can take the parameter by reference:

```
void foo(ClassA& x) //or const ClassA
```

You'll be able to pass both instances of `ClassA` or `ClassB`, and use RTTI to determine which type it actually is inside the function.

Alternatively, you can pass a pointer to `ClassA`, but references are to be preferred where possible.

Answer (score 2):

Declare the function parameter to be a pointer or a reference to an `ClassA` instance (don't pass it by value or the input instance will get sliced at runtime).  Then you can use `dynamic_cast` if you need to access `ClassB`-specific functionality.  For example:

```
class ClassA
{
public:
    int a;

    virtual ~ClassA() {}
    void DoSomething();
};

class ClassB : public ClassA
{
public:
    int b;
    void DoSomethingElse();
};

void func(ClassA *obj)
{
    int a = obj->a;
    obj->DoSomething();

    ClassB *objB = dynamic_cast<ClassB*>(obj);
    if (objB)
    {
        int b = objB->b;
        objB->DoSomethingElse();
    }
}

int main()
{
    ClassA a;
    func(&a);

    ClassB b;
    func(&b);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea with a bit of indirection. The function `Consumer::accept` accepts both objects of type `A` and type `B`, and the specific behaviour is implemented by *those* classes rather than by your consumer.

```
struct Consumer;

struct A
{
    virtual ~A() { }
    virtual int use(Consumer &);
};

struct B : A
{
    virtual int use(Consumer &);
};

struct Consumer
{
    void accept(A & x)
    { 
        int n = x.use(*this);
        do_more_stuff(n);
    }

    void do_more_stuff(int);

    // ...
};
```